# How to map a custom domain name created in freenom.com to a Windows Azure VM with Public IP

Tags: azure, dns, virtual

I have searched the net and cannot find an answer to this question. I have created a .ga domain with freenom.com.

I created two dns records in freenom.com. The A record maps to the public ip of the virtual machine and the cname record maps to the azure domain name - xxxxx.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com. I set the ttl in both records to be 3600.

I give some hours for the dns records to propagate and try to do an nslookup on my .ga domain but it does not seem to exist. I try pinging, browsing the url but it seems that my domain does not exist.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does http://digwebinterface.com/ give you on your domain name ?

Answer (score 1):

For VM, you need to specify it on the Cloud Service level - did you do everything according to the [official guidance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name-portal/)?

If you use non-classic VM (ARM), then the situation is a little more complicated - you may go with [that approach](http://www.seesharprun.net/arm_custom_domain_vm/) or with the [Azure DNS service](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0dcf29b0-1e80-4dd9-b271-ea42fed6aa64/how-to-set-a-custom-domain-name-for-azure-virtual-machine-arm-mode?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows).

Comment: Thanks Alex for your response. I used the Resource Manager deployed VM option (new). I'll have a look at the links you've provided and inform you appropriately.

Comment: Hi Alex, after going through the info contained in the suggested links, I've decided to use Azure DNS instead because I've performed all the requirements mentioned in the links provided but my domain still is not able to propagate to the .ga TLD nameservers. I've also raised a ticket with freenom.com but they have not responded back to me to date. The only sacrifice, I've got to make with using Azure DNS is paying for this cloud service. Freenom.com nameservers are free. Will let you know on how I go.

Comment: @SutherlandNele Azure DNS is the great option. Please let me know if that will work.

Comment: Hi @Sutherland Nele I have made your Freenom exact same configuration work with Azure Web App let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your VM Name looks like : "name.cloudapp.azure.com". By default public IP address is created not static address that means you can't use DNS record on it.

If you want to use different domain name like "xxxxtest.com" then you have 2 options:

**Use 'CNAME' DNS record**

**Use reserved IP record on Azure and 'A' DNS record**

Refer below link for more details:
http://byalexblog.net/custom-domain-name-for-azure-vm